# Stylus: fetching deep values from a hash in a function

Tags: function, hash, stylus

I'm newly converted to Stylus from Sass and a little new to the functionality. I'm having trouble accessing deeper level hash values in my functions. Here's an example:

```
$type-scale = {
    small: {
        base-font-size: 16px,
        base-line-height: 1.3
        }
    medium: {
        base-font-size: 18px,
        base-line-height: 1.4
    }
    large: {
        base-font-size: 22px,
        base-line-height: 1.5
    }
}

font-scale()
    scale = arguments[0]
    if scale in $type-scale
        font-size: base-font-size
        line-height: base-line-height
    else
        error('Not a defined scale')

.foo
    font-scale('small')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `[]` to get the property value defined by a variable. And for `base-font-size` and `base-line-height` you can use normal dot notation:

```
$type-scale = {
  small: {
    base-font-size: 16px,
    base-line-height: 1.3
  }
  medium: {
    base-font-size: 18px,
    base-line-height: 1.4
  }
  large: {
    base-font-size: 22px,
    base-line-height: 1.5
  }
}

font-scale(scale)
  if scale in $type-scale
    font-size: $type-scale[scale].base-font-size
    line-height: $type-scale[scale].base-line-height
  else
    error('Not a defined scale')

.foo
  font-scale('small')
```